# Paho MQTT: unsent messages queue and reboot

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm developing an application with Paho MQTT and QOS = 1. I know for sure that if the network is not available for a certain period of time the client puts every message in a queue and sends them when the connection is established again. 
What I want to understand it's if the queue is saved even when the application itself gets restarted (for instance a machine reboot). If not, how do you suggest to implement it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're storing the unsent messages in a list within your program, then no, they won't be saved when the application reboots. To do this you could save the unsent messages in an external file and have the application read from it and send them once connection is established

Comment: So do you suggest to save every new message in a list and eventually remove it when it gets published, right? I should also export that list to a file every time it changes.

Comment: Yes, but to optimise it, you can export the list to an external file only if the connection to the MQTT server fails.